# Multiple Template Matching

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to do Multiple template matching on teeth.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

X_data=[]
files = glob.glob ('C:/Users/amuly/Pictures/Saved Pictures/template/*.jpg')

img=cv2.imread('C:/Users/amuly/Pictures/Saved Pictures/teeth.jpeg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

for myfile in files:
    temp=cv2.imread(myfile)   
    w,h=temp.shape[::-1]
```

I am getting the error    **too many values to unpack** after this line.
Kindly help.

```
    res=cv2.matchTemplate(gray,temp,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold=0.86
    loc=np.where(res>=threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img,pt,(pt[0]+w,pt[1]+h),(0,255,255),2)


cv2.imshow('Detected',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case your image is in color, the `temp.shape` will return a tuple with 3 values. You can't unpack that into 2 variables, you need three.

Maybe you also have a double colon by accident in your code.

```
 w,h=temp.shape[::-1]
```

This would work and remove last element from tuple, so that you can unpack to two variables.

```
 w,h=temp.shape[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Multiple template matching using OpenCV Python-

Image Source-Google images

Link for code and image files-https://github.com/Pawankumar2925/multiple-template-matching

Cropping software- Windows Paint

```
import cv2    
import numpy as np    
count=[0 ,0 ,0,0]
threshold=[0.9,0.9,0.85,0.9]
img_bgr= cv2.imread('myphoto.png')
img_gray=cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

templates = [ cv2.imread('template'+str(i)+'.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) for i in 
range(1,5) ]
w1,h1=templates[0].shape[::-1]
w2,h2=templates[1].shape[::-1]
w3,h3=templates[2].shape[::-1]
w4,h4=templates[3].shape[::-1]

result1=cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,templates[0],cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
result2=cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,templates[1],cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
result3=cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,templates[2],cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
result4=cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,templates[3],cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

loc1=np.where(result1>=threshold[0])
loc2=np.where(result2>=threshold[1])
loc3=np.where(result3>=threshold[2])
loc4=np.where(result4>=threshold[3])

for pt1 in zip(*loc1[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_bgr,pt1,(pt1[0]+w1,pt1[1]+h1),(0,255,0),2)
    count[0]=count[0]+1
for pt2 in zip(*loc2[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_bgr,pt2,(pt2[0]+w2,pt2[1]+h2),(255,0,0),2)
    count[1]=count[1]+1
for pt3 in zip(*loc3[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_bgr,pt3,(pt3[0]+w3,pt3[1]+h3),(0,0,255),2)
    count[2]=count[2]+1
for pt4 in zip(*loc4[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_bgr,pt4,(pt4[0]+w3,pt4[1]+h3),(0,0,255),2)
    count[3]=count[3]+1



print "Circle"
print count[0]
print "Square"
print count[1]
print "Star"
print count[2]
print "Triangle"
print count[3]

cv2.imshow("image",img_bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> Thanks and Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just write source code here without explanation. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)